# swift tableview reload data issue - missing elements in custom cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I am new to iOS programming, and the language I'm using is Swift in Xcode 6.0.1. I am currently implementing a chat functionality in my app. I have used web socket to send/receive messages from server and it's working fine. The problem I am having is displaying the sent/received messages.

I created a UIViewController with a table view, a textfield and button to send messages. I have applied all the necessary constraints to fit auto-layout, and implemented the required delegates. Every time a user sends/receives a message, a new message string is added to the data source (array of strings), and then I call:

```
self.tableView.reloadData
```

The table consists of custom cells with an image and a label inside a view. It's working fine for a few send/receive, but after some time, the table view messes up and only the images inside the custom cells remain, as shown in this image [image]

This is my code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

{
    var cell: customMessageCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier ,forIndexPath: indexPath) as customMessageCell

    if(messages[indexPath.row].contains("Fiona")){
        cell.myAvatar.hidden = true
        cell.myMessage.hidden = true
        cell.myMessageBubble.hidden = true

        cell.yourMessage.text = messages[indexPath.row]
        cell.yourAvatar.hidden = false
    }else{
        cell.yourAvatar.hidden = true
        cell.yourMessage.hidden = true
        cell.yourMessageBubble.hidden = true

        cell.myMessage.text = messages[indexPath.row]
        cell.myAvatar.hidden = false
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    return cell
}
```

I have checked that the message array is actually incrementing, but when I do a reload data in the table view, the issue arises. How do I fix this? Is this a better way to insert a new cell in the table instead of (add to data source + table reload)? Thanks!

Comment: Please show your code - in particular `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: here issue is that when you scrolll the value hide or show on each scroll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a cell is reused you need to completely reset the properties appropriately.  Your code hides the message and bubble but doesn't unhide them, so a cell that was previously used for an 'outgoing' message may be reused for an 'incoming' message and the message/bubble will be hidden.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

{
    var cell: customMessageCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier ,forIndexPath: indexPath) as customMessageCell

    if(messages[indexPath.row].contains("Fiona")){
        cell.myAvatar.hidden = true
        cell.myMessage.hidden = true
        cell.myMessageBubble.hidden = true

        cell.yourMessage.text = messages[indexPath.row]
        cell.yourAvatar.hidden = false
        cell.yourMessageBubble.hidden = false
        cell.yourMessage.hidden = false;
    }else{
        cell.yourAvatar.hidden = true
        cell.yourMessage.hidden = true
        cell.yourMessageBubble.hidden = true

        cell.myMessage.text = messages[indexPath.row]
        cell.myAvatar.hidden = false
        cell.myMessageBubble.hidden = false
        cell.myMessage.hidden = false
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I overlook such simple thing. >_<